# How to make a sparse matrix (e.g. dgCMatrix) readable by a function that requires a standard matrix class form?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I would need to use a quite large sparse matrix as panel structure (basically the element *s* in *y ~ x1 + x2 + ... | s* ) into the rqpd function https://rdrr.io/rforge/rqpd/man/rqpd.html) which usually requires a standard matrix form or a simple id column.:

rqpd(formula, panel = panel(), data = parent.frame(),
na.action, subset, contrasts = NULL, control = NULL, ...)

As expected, rqpd doesn't accept the sparse equivalent and, of course, the standard matrix is too large to fit memory requirements. This is what I get if I use the sparse equivalent of the matrix *fe*:

```
## define the sparse equivalent of the matrix that identifies fixed effect structure in rqpd
fe <- sparse.model.matrix(~id_z.f:id_j.f-1)

## fit rqpd...
> rqpdfit <- rqpd(y  ~ x  | fe  , control=list(tmpmax=1000000), panel(lambda = 1,taus=c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9),tauw=rep(1/5, 5), method="pfe")) 
*Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data,  : 
  invalid type (S4) for variable 'fe'*
```

Is there a way to let the function read the dgCMatrix equivalent (or other sparse forms) of *fe*?

Comment: Not without implementing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Roland for your prompt reply! So you mean there is no solution to this problem unless I find a way to use a standard matrix?

Comment: it's simpler to find equivalent for `rqpd` that can carry sparse matrix input in other packages